# WP Simple Download Monitor File Download URL Redirect issues

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

In .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =sdmon=software_download/software1.exe
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://download.domain.com/software1.exe? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =sdmon=software_download/software2.exe
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://download.domain.com/software2.exe? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

These rules redirect `http:www.domain.com/index.php?sdmon=software_download/software1.exe` 
to `http:www.domain.com/software1.exe`
....

My question is : How to combine the 2 sets of rules into a single one.

Comment: Is the second rule supposed to go to `software2.exe`, not just `software2`?

Comment: sorry for missing exe . ive fixed that.  Have u got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sdmon=software_download/software(\d+)\.exe$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://download.domain.com/software%1.exe? [L,R=301]
```

That'll work for `software1`, `software5600`, and anywhere else in between.

**Edit:**

For any exe name, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sdmon=software_download/([^/\.]+)\.exe$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://download.domain.com/%1.exe? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks! What if  hello.exe   hi.exe     ladygaga.exe ?  I mean, not the number variation, but different exe name.  O(∩_∩)O~

Comment: @Chang See edit.